# Picture degration when importing into FCP

Tags: video-quality

When I Import from computer or download from camera into FCP program I am experiencing degration of the quality of film, and that includes analog, and digital 1080p down or up loads.  What am I doing wrong?

Details, I am uploading old video footage from VHS which looks pretty good when uploading to computer, but loses quality when imported into FCP. I am also uploading digital footage at 1080p from my Sony camcorder.

Both lose picture quality when loaded into FCP. When I up-load into FCP I always import at highest quality, no proxy quality.

My computer is a Mac, Processor 2x3 Ghz Quad Core Intel Xeon Memory 4 GB 800 MHz DDR2 FB-DIMM Graphics ATI Radeon HD 5870 1024 MB. I am using Elgato to up-load VHS footage.

Comment: Welcome! We'll need some more details in order to help you out. First, in order to figure out what you might be doing wrong, can you tell us exactly what you are doing? What artifacts are you seeing? Can you share samples of your source files or screenshots before and after?

Comment: To give you reliably smooth playback in FCP the preview quality is often lower. You can set the preview to higher quality, but it may affect the performance depending on your machine. https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/final-cut-pro/ver2fd7a8b94/mac

Comment: It doesn't affect the final quality however.

Comment: Please append details from your comments directly into your question (click Edit at the bottom of it, then copy/paste from your comments).